# git + lighttpd: how to defined permissions for users and groups?

Tags: git, permissions, lighttpd, read-write

I've successfully setup git together with lighttpd. Now I was wondering, if I define user A and B, how could I give A read/write access to repository X, and only read permissions for user B ?

These users exist only in my lighttpd environment and are not real users on my system so things like 'chown' cannot be used!

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Then you would need to add an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) [like gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) (usually [coupled with gitweb](http://www.trueelena.org/computers/howto/git_server_with_gitolite_gitweb_and_lighttpd.html)):

That would allow to "declare" user A and B (even if there is no actual accounts for them), and given them the correct right access.